# Can't resize TextArea when text exceed TextArea height Tailwind CSS (Daisy UI)

Tags: reactjs, textarea, tailwind-css, daisyui

Im trying to enable resizing of TextArea in a react application using TailWind CSS, however when I do enable resizing, when the text exceeds the height of TextArea I'm unable to resize the TextArea anymore.

Below are screenshots of what is happening

1. Before Text exceeds height

[Before Text exceeds height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTP1D.png)

2. After Text exceeds height

[After Text exceeds height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFQee.png)

Below is the component created for the TextArea

```
<div className='form-control w-full'>
  <label className='label'>
    <span className='label-text text-primary'>{title}</span>
  </label>
  <textarea
    placeholder={placeholder}
    className={`textarea w-full resize-y ${
      value !== text ? 'bg-green-100' : 'bg-white'
    }`}
    value={text}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setText(e.target.value);
      debounced(e.target.value);
    }}
  />
</div>
```

This TextArea component is wrapped in the following code

```
<div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap">
  {descriptions.map((field: CollapsibleInputField, i: number) => (
    <div
      key={i}
      className={
        field.placeholder === "English" ? "w-full pr-2" : "w-1/2 pr-2"
      }
    >
      <TextAreaContainer
        id={field.id}
        value={field.data}
        placeholder={field.placeholder}
        title={field.title}
      />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What classes are you applying with `textarea`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying use the resize to let the textarea dynamic according to the text into there. But, you need observer the element using the ref for example and increase the height of textarea dynamic.

This could solve it the problem.

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);

const handleInput = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  if (ref.current) {
    ref.current.style.height = "auto";
    ref.current.style.height = `${e.target.scrollHeight - 16}px`;
  }
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <section>
      <textarea
        ref={ref}
        rows={1}
        placeholder="Enter text here..."
        onInput={handleInput}
      />
    </section>
  </div>
);
```